# How to define macros only for algorithm environment in my class file

Tags: macros, document-classes, scoping

I have a `doc.tex` and a `myclass.cls` file, and trying to keep the first as clean as possible.

I need to define in `myclass.cls` some macros to use and be visible only inside the two environments: `algorithm` and `clase` (the last is just a modification of `algorithm`).

myclass.cls

```
...
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,spanish,onelanguage]{algorithm2e}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{clase}
\newenvironment{clase}[1][htb]{%
    \renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{Clase}% Update algorithm name
    \let\c@algocf\c@clase% Update algorithm counter
    \begin{algorithm}[#1]%
}{\end{algorithm}}
\makeatother
...
```

doc.tex

```
...
\begin{document}
...
\begingroup
    \definecolor{green2}{RGB}{0,156,0}
    \newcommand\true{\textcolor{red2}{$true$}}
    \newcommand\store{\textcolor{green2}{$store()$}}
    % And 40+ others like these
    % I want them in myclass.cls and avoid that \begingroup

    \begin{clase}
        % Defined macros are visible here
    \end{clase}
    \paragraph{Another stuff} I don't need the macros to be visible here
    \begin{algorithm}
        % also visible here
    \end{algorithm}
\endgroup
...
```

Comment: It would be helpful which of the various `algorithm` and `OhterEnvi` environments you are using and what is inside of your `myclass.cls` that you try to build around your `doc.tex`  ;-)

Comment: question (not answer, as I wrote) updated, I hope it is helpful :). Thanks again

Comment: The short answer is that you refine the algorithm environment such that those macros are defined in and only in its scope. macro definitions are local unless made global explicitly. Check out `etoolbox` package for patching environment

Comment: @YanZhou: `\AtBeginEnvironment{clase}{\newcommand{\true}{...}}` should do as well

Comment: @ChristianHupfer yes, I forgot that.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer. I did it with `\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithm}{...}` because `clase` is `algorithm` too :-). Can you state an answer to mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If code changes should be done for an environment only sometimes `\AtBeginEnvironment` is a better option than `\patchcmd`, but this depends on the real application.

Since `\renewcommand` is not global, the meaning of a macro changed within an environment does not leak outside, so `\AtBeginEnvironment` is a suitable choice.

I've reduced the O.P's example to a minimal one, for some fake environment `foo`. (Of course, in a real world example, the environment isn't defined usually in the same file and then changed afterwards with `\AtBeginEnvironment`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\foobar}{This is foobar}

\newenvironment{foo}{%
\bfseries\foobar


}{}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{foo}{%
  \renewcommand{\foobar}{This is foobar inside foo}%
}{}


\begin{document}

Foobar before foo: \foobar

\begin{foo}
Hello World
\end{foo}

Foobar after foo: \foobar


\end{document}
```

[image]